# Add element to numpy array without changing the name

Tags: python, numpy, loops, append

I want to add a single element : `-globals()["q"+str(i)][0][u]` to the array `mainarray` while being inside a loop.

```
for i in mylist:
    for u in 0,5,10:
      np.append(mainarray['C'][u][i],-globals()["q"+str(i)][0][u])
```

After finishing the loop the changes are not save, how can I achieve that?

Comment: The problem with my solution was that we would be making some of the elements in the array bigger than others. Try adding an entire row of null or zero values and then appending the values in your loop. Even better, you won't need to append, but only to insert a value in the last location

Comment: I solved it, I created an empty object inside the required loops, Then I replaced each value with the desired values.

Comment: can you post your solution and mark the question as solved please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a new array with a "+1" dimension of length.

```
newarray=pd.Series([])
newarray[at_type][at1] = np.zeros((old_length+1))
```

Then I started the loop.

```
for i in mylist:
    for u in 0,5,10:
      newarray['C'][u][i]=np.append(mainarray['C'][u][i],-globals()["q"+str(i)][0][u])
```